# display different web pages in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am developing a web application using *JSP* & *Servlets*.

I am trying to find alternatives to *HTML Frames*. So I have search and I found that it can be done using *CSS*.

So I have a `CSS` which divides screen into three parts:

1. Header
2. Content
3. Footer

**HTML code**

```
<body>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
        content here
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        Header here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <div id="footer">
        Footer here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So now I want to display different pages in each `div` tag. My aim behind doing this was putting code of `menu's` in single *HTML* file and then display that file in all other web pages as a `Header`. So is there any way of doing this?

[Note: This is one way I have found after searching so far,  So let me know if there are any better options which can be alternatives to `Frames`]

Comment: yes it is possible, but you'll need more than just javascript, jquery, html and css.

Comment: @HeHui can you elaborate what will be required?

Comment: fix div s using css like position absolute and include them in which page you want

Comment: If you're developing something using JSP, please tag your question accordingly... JSP !== JavaScript

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for pointing out mistake, I will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this one:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
```

In jsp servlets this is to be used.

example:

```
 <div id="content-wrapper">
    <%@ include file="content.jsp" %>
</div>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</div>
```

#### [Read More here...](http://roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/use-of-include-tag-in-jsp.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jsp include directive like this :

```
<jsp:include page="include.jsp" />
```

Or you can iframe :

```
<iframe src="htmlservlet/file.html" />
```

Comment: Thanks for alternative as iframe(and +1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSP include directive:

```
<%@ include file="some_file.jsp"%>
```

Allows you to build reusable bits of your view which can be included into many pages.

[simple oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using apache Tiles for page layouts: http://tiles.apache.org/

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
</div>
<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</div>
```

And configuration

```
<definition name="myapp.homepage" template="/layouts/mylayout.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/tiles/header.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="content" value="/tiles/content.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: Thanks for alternative as `Apache Tiles`(and +1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden divs or Jquery to show diffrent content in the Content area of your site when the menu item i clicked, sort of like the bookmark option but with hidden information..

this way it will not be seen by the general public until the link is clicked and the content is swapped.. all the code can be on one HTML page besides the styling and main jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

```
head:
<style>
#head
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:200px;
}
</style>
<div id='head'>
</div>


footer:
<style>
#footer
{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
}
</style>
<div id='footer'>
</div>
now add them where ever you want in between them write content
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am already having a `CSS` with me, i just wanted to display different pages in different `DIV` tags